# Python interactive interpreter in hashbang line

Tags: django, bpython

For my django projects, I wanted to write a simple replacement for `manage.py shell` to take advantage of bpython.  Essentially all it does is run `setup_environ(settings)` and then import some common models (User, etc.)

in any case, everything works fine when I run `bpython -i bshell.py` (my script is named bshell.py).  Then I thought I'd get clever and set the hashbang line to `#!/usr/bin/env bpython -i` to make it even simpler, and this worked on the OSX but is not working now in Ubuntu (10.10).

`#!/usr/bin/env python -i` also does not work, but `#!/usr/bin/env bpython` works (but obviously doesn't drop into the interactive prompt).

It's a small point, but over the course of my life it will save me hundreds of "bpython -i"s if I can just run my script as `./bshell.py` (really I'm just curious).  Any ideas why it's not working on Ubuntu?

I should note I'm in a virtualenv, and I already double checked that line endings are *nix style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29#Portability):

```
Another portability problem is the interpretation of the command arguments. 
Some systems, including Linux, do not split up the arguments; for example, 
when running the script with the first line like,

#!/usr/bin/env python -c

That is, python -c will be passed as one argument to /usr/bin/env, 
rather than two arguments.
```

If it's no big deal, you're probably better off using the actual path to `bpython` instead of going through `/usr/bin/env`.